# convert column to comma seperarted string with python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string

I have a data frame as:

```
id.      name
123      sanfrancisco
124      losangeles
12356    washington  
123441   orlando
```

I need to convert this name column into comma sep string value as:

```
'san francisco', 'losangeles', 'washington', 'orlando'
```

I've changed this into list but i cannot use array, i need string value.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to convert it to csv? If so you could directly use the `to_csv` method. Otherwise, to get the exact string you mentioned you could do:

```
name = df.name.tolist()
string = "'" + name[0]+"'"
for n in name[1:]:
  string += ", '" + n + "'"
```

Output:

```
'sanfrancisco', 'losangeles', 'washington', 'orlando'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
', '.join(df.name.to_list())

 'sanfrancisco, losangeles, washington, orlando'
```

### Edit:

If you need the quotes:

```
', '.join(df.name.apply("'{}'".format).to_list()) 

'sanfrancisco', 'losangeles', 'washington', 'orlando'
```

Comment: just a small adjustment is needed here, i need 'sanfrancisco', 'losangeles' etc. claws before and after all string values

Comment: @lincolnab check the edit